# Wordpress multiple subdomains and cookies

Tags: wordpress, session-cookies, subdomain

I want to apologies for my bad english.

I've a single Wordpress install with multiple subdomains. It means that you can access any content with any subdomain, for example /my-post/ can be accessed via domain.com/my-post/, sub1.domain.com/my-post/, sub2.domain.com/my-post/ etc... It's not a redirection, all url are dynamically generated based on http_host.

My issue is that cookies are set only on a per-domain basis. Not like Wordpress multisite allowing to be connected on all subdomains accross the network, with a single install I'm not able to allow it.

I've tried to set define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com' ); but with no luck. When I log into domain.com I'm not logged in subdomains.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Thanks a lot for you precious help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

By default, WordPress uses an md5 hash of the site URL as the `COOKIEHASH`.

In your case, I believe the site URL will be dynamically populated by the server request, so you might define a constant with something like this

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_HOME', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

To share login cookies, both *(domain and subdomain)* should have the same `COOKIEHASH`. So I think defining the `COOKIEHASH` will do.

```
define( 'COOKIEHASH', md5( 'https://yourdomain.com' ) );
```